# Return correct DataTable row ID from ahref button

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have searched high and low, maybe I missed something...

I have a DataTable that gets populated with records. As I loop through all records (using PHP), the record ID is added as well as a cancel button, invoice button (using ahref) for each row. I also add a hidden input with id="ID" that captures the record ID (1, 2, 3, etc) for each row. I am displaying 3 rows per table page with the option to go to page 2, 3 etc.

When I get the value of the ID, it keeps on returning the top row ID i.e if row ID is 10 at the top, 11 middle and 12 bottom row, if I select the row 12, the ID returned is the top one ID=10.

I use the ID as part of a URL build, but obviously need the correct ID to be returned.

Not sure if the problem exist because all of my hidden inputs (22 as per the database table row count) now have a id named ID?

Will appreciate help on where I am going wrong, thank you!

[image]

Code for table with ahref button - table

```
<td style="color: #0d9b84; text-align: center; width: 30px;"><?php echo "#".$part_result->ID; ?></td>
```

Hidden input -

```
<input type="hidden" id="ID" value="<?php echo $part_result->ID;?>" />
```

aHref - both functions is called correctly -

```
<a href="#" onclick="getadvertprice(); gotourlinvoice();" class="btn btn-success btn-block" style="color: #4cff00;">Invoice To Client<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
```

Lastly, the javascript used to return the data and build the URL, also, no errors, just the incorrect ID that gets selected -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
}

    function gotourlinvoice() {
        var url = "mynextpagehere.php";

        var dataID = document.getElementById("ID").value;           
        var partnumber = document.getElementById("partnumber").value;
        var partname = document.getElementById("partname").value;
        var invoicenumber = prompt("Please enter your DMS Invoice Number:", "Required: DMS Invoice Number");

        if (invoicenumber == null || invoicenumber == "") {

            return;
        } else {
            datalinks = invoicenumber;
        }

        var parameters = {
            ID: dataID,
            PartNumber: partnumber,
            PartName: partname,
            InvoiceNumber: datalinks
        };

        var fulllink = buildUrl(url, parameters);

        fulllink = encodeURIComponent(fulllink);

        alert("Your selection of record - ID: " + dataID + " has been saved as \"Invoiced\" with DMS Invoice Number - \"" + datalinks + "\"");
        alert(fulllink);

        //document.location.href = fulllink;
    }
```

Comment: Why not to add id number to function call in your php generation? Like this `<a href="#" onclick="getadvertprice(<ID>); gotourlinvoice(<ID>);" class="btn btn-success btn-block" style="color: #4cff00;">Invoice To Client<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>`

Comment: Thank you Maksim. I will try your solution in a few. How would I still grab the ID though as I am passing this on to the next page via PHP REQUEST?

Comment: @Maksim, just tried, still returning the top row ID, not the selected row ID

Comment: Maybe you can use JSON response?